# Modular inverse of a matrix in Java

Tags: java, matrix, jama

I'm trying to work out the modular inverse of a matrix, how could this be done in Java?

So far I've found the package Jama package - http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/
Can be used for inverse and matrix multiplication, however I'm stumped trying to find the mouldar inverse of a matrix...

This is exactly what I am trying to achieve here: http://planetcalc.com/3324/

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to implement the algorithm yourself, or are you looking for a library that will do it for you?

Comment: Either option.  I don't have the knowledge to implement the algorithm myself so found myself looking for a library that could do it for me.

Comment: OK.  The mathematics is fairly complicated if you don't know what you're doing, and I don't know where to start looking for a library for this - it's highly specialised.  Probably your best bet is to get the Javascript from that page that you linked to, and try to convert it to Java.

Answer (score -1):

You can look at this package:

https://code.google.com/p/jmatharray/

I see it supports inverse, but not sure out modular inverse.

There is also this library which is well supported and supports several variations of inverse:

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/linear.html

Comment: I don't believe that either of those two resources contains a solution to the OP's problem.